# How can I distribute a sorting scheme

Tags: biblatex, sorting, package-writing

I have made a personal sorting scheme for my final bibliography. It's like the `nty` scheme but anonymous work before the non-anonymous work.

As it's a usual need in my field (classical philology) I would like to publish it.

But, as I know, there is no way in `biblatex` to publish a sorting scheme in a file, as there is for example .cbx or .bbx file.

Of course, I could distribute it as a .sty file, but that would imply that users should:

- load the package for sorting
- load the `biblatex` package with the sorting option.

It will be a two step and not intuitive method.

Does anybody have you any other idea ?

Comment: If you feel that the [tag:package-writing] tag is inappropriate, feel free to remove it.

Comment: oh, no, it could be appropriate

Comment: This isn't really possible - normally a sorting scheme is part of a style (like with `biblatex-apa` which has its own sorting scheme). The easiest way is to just post the macro and have people paste it into their pre-amble ...

Comment: Ok. So it could be a .sty, without pastebin to make... I will think if it will be better to send my contribution inside a specific style to philology or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can distribute the sorting schema as a normal biblatex style with options to load other biblatex styles. Here is a proof of concept

`mystyle.bbx`

```
\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{loadMySortingSchemaOnTopOf}[numeric]{
  \RequireBibliographyStyle{#1}
  \RequireCitationStyle{#1}
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{mysortingschema}{
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{author}}
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loadMySortingSchemaOnTopOf,sorting=mysortingschema}
```

`mystyle.cbx`

```
\ifcsundef{ifcbx:parens}{}{\csundef{ifcbx:parens}}
\RequireCitationStyle{numeric}
```

Then the sorting schema can be simply used with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=test]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{key1}
\cite{key2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

or by specifying a style to be extended with the new sorting schema

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=test,loadMySortingSchemaOnTopOf=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{key1}
\cite{key2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```